# When refering to the Apps subdomain (apps.ubuntu.com) with a button, should I add anything to indicate it as a resource?

Tags: discussion

I saw this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117048/how-to-install-the-new-gnome-boxes) and wondered about the idea of mentioning https://apps.ubuntu.com in the text (additional to having the button: 
[image])

How would be a nice way ?

Comment: This is a bit unclear, do you mean, should you also mention apps.ubuntu.com in text, even if you have the button their?

Comment: @MarkKirby Yes.

Comment: Then no because a big red button does the job just fine :) and, if I recall correctly, that is not updated any more, nothing for 16.04 on there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the post you linked is a perfect example of a nice way to do it.